# Unable to resize Master Shapes in Visio 2010

Tags: microsoft-visio

I am trying to create my own stencil template by editing the existing stencils from MS Visio 2010. However, whenever I try to resize a shape to fit the other's width and height (Right Click Master > Edit Master > Edit Master Shape), it still displays its original height and width upon drag and drop to worksheet:

[image: resizing]

Comment: Which shape is it? The size of some shapes is determined by Visio's built-in addins.

Comment: I am trying to resize the "Customer service" stencil found under Flowchart > Department (US Units).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The master that it is actually taking data from is the one in the Document Stencil.
More Shapes -> Show Document Stencil
and remove the master that is there already.